# Regex to capture quotation mark followed by a non-punctuation character

Tags: javascript, regex

I had the following regex to match opening quotation marks:

```
/'(?=\b)/g
```

But then I realized that it also captures stuff like `don't` and `it's`.

So I added another rule:

```
/'(?=\b[^a-zA-Z])/g
```

Capture an opening quotation mark not followed by a letter (`t` and `s` in this case). But now none of the quotation marks are being highlighted.

Did I modify the regex in a wrong way?

**EDIT:**

Oh, I realized my dumb mistake. Anyway, here's what I want to do:

> "two 'three'"
>
> "four don't it's "

I want to match the opening `'` in `three` but not the `'`s in `don't` and `it's`

Comment: Well, I would think most opening quotation marks are followed by a letter? Without knowing the details of what kind of text you want to run the regex on, it may be better to check that it's not preceded by a letter?

Comment: Welcome to the edge-cases of regular expressions when used with an irregular language.

Comment: Can you provide us with examples of a few items that you would want to match and a few that you wouldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to your last EDIT, this Regex `/[\.\,\;\?\!\s]+'/g` is what you are looking for, it matches quotation in sentences like `'three'` and skips what you need (sentences like `don't  and it's`).

[**Here's a DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/uJ6uS3/2).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this regex to match quotes but skip those cases like `don't` `it's` etc:

```
/(?:^|[^a-zA-Z])'|'(?![a-zA-Z])/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nZ7nV5/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex to only match opening `'`

```
/(?!\b)'/g
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vU5gL8/1) on your testcases

Answer (score 2):

You have your look-around in the wrong place. You want to find instances where a quote is preceded by nothing, and proceeded by characters. This would probably work

```
/\b'\B/
```